# Composite Keys on table with other properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a composite key on a table that's not a junction table, because it contains another field, an order property.

I am having all sorts of problems getting the composite key to work. This is what the basis looks like:

```
public class User : BaseModel
{

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserQuestionGroup> QuestionGroups { get; set; }

    // ..... //
}

public class QuestionGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    // ..... //
}

// This is where I'm having problems with the mapping
public class UserQuestionGroup
{        

    [Key,ForeignKey("User"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId;

    [Key, ForeignKey("QuestionGroupId"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int QuestionGroupId;

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }

    [Column("Sort")]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Plus.DAL.UserQuestionGroup: : EntityType 'UserQuestionGroup' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
UserQuestionGroups: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserQuestionGroups' is based on type 'UserQuestionGroup' that has no keys defined.
```

Each user can have many question groups, and each question group can have many users. I am using a repository pattern to access the data access layer (DAL).

Can someone please point me in the right direction, either with Attributes if possible or using the DbModelBuilder.

I am using EF 6 with MVC 5.1.

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change keys from fields to properties. Also you should mark navigation properties with `ForeignKey` attributes, instead of keys:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int UserId { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int QuestionGroupId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual User User { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("QuestionGroupId")]
public virtual QuestionGroup QuestionGroup { get; set; }
```

That will generate following table:

[image]

NOTE: I suggest you to use fluent mapping API with Code First - that will keep your entities clear from database-related attributes. Same mapping can be done in following way:

```
public class UserQuestionGroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserQuestionGroup>
{
    public UserQuestionGroupMapping()
    {
        HasKey(uqg => new { uqg.UserId, uqg.QuestionGroupId });
        Property(uqg => uqg.Order).HasColumnName("Sort");

        HasRequired(uqg => uqg.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.QuestionGroups).HasForeignKey(uqg => uqg.UserId);

        HasRequired(uqg => uqg.QuestionGroup)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(uqg => uqg.QuestionGroupId);
    }
}
```

Then just add mappings to model builder on model creating in your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserQuestionGroupMap());
    // add other maps
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't think it was working, but I forgot to change my fields to properties! This was doing my head in, so thanks heaps!